# Unknown mouse dpi / comparisons

Tags: mouse, dpi

I have this mouse right here currently:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826105164

I am trying to figure out what the dpi of said mouse is, and if that dpi would be the same on optical as it would be on laser.

Comment: It's interesting that you prefer optical over laser. Any particular reason why?

Comment: Just don't like the feel when using it. I know it's more accurate but I found it taking longer to move across the screen and setting it to move quicker just wasn't the same for me.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google suggests your mouse is either 400 or 800. It certainly won't be much higher if it's just optical.

I'd recommend buying one with a shape similar to your current one then adjusting DPI until it feels comfortable. There's even mice available with weight kits that you may find useful.
Don't forget to keep windows mouse sense at 6/11 too.

I'd also go with laser:

[image: Optical vs laser]
<sub>(source: [engineersgarage.com](https://www.engineersgarage.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/Original/wysiwyg_imageupload/28714/logitech_graph.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Yeah it's currently at 6 right now.

Comment: I found this manual here, I think this is my mouse? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ol3u6i0ph00ods4/5898713d7f6a5192c8da2054f15070901949aebb.pdf What does 400 points per inch mean? 400 dpi?